# How to use a method in a .java class in its layout .xml class?

Tags: android

I had a problem when trying to put multiple images that makes the emulator crashes. One solution was this
You put the images in the Assets folder instead of the Drawable folder, but I don't know how to get the return of this method and put it as the src image of an ImageView

```
public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: you can't do it in XML. Try to add in java code

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do but initializing a drawable image in such method doesn't initialize it in the R.class so I cannot access it.

Comment: Try imageView.setImageDrawable(getAssetImage(context,filename));

Comment: Do you think I add it like this in the Oncreate method ?

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_banana);
  ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  try {
   Drawable x=getAssetImage(this,"bananarecipewithwords");
   img.setImageDrawable(getAssetImage(this,"bananarecipewithwords"));
   System.out.println("TRY");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("CATCH");
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  
  
  
  addListenerOnButton();
  
 }

Comment: Fine It should work. change img.setImageDrawable(getAssetImage(this,"bananarecipewithwords")); to img.setImageDrawable(x));

Comment: Not working .. it's giving a blank page

Comment: edit your question and post your complete activity and xml code